# Adj. + 到 to express an extent

Tags: expressions, adverbs, adjectives

I've just stumbled across this sentence:

> "吃土" 表示自己没有钱了，很穷，穷到只能吃土的状态了

I'm interested in *穷到只能吃土的状态了*. It means "so poor that they can only eat soil". But it seems that adjective + 到 + description is a structure to say "so ... that ...".

1. Is it in fact a structure to create such sentences?
2. *只能吃土的状态了* - I don't even know if I should treat it as a sentence or as a noun. So: what should come after 到?
3. Is this sentence correct? 累到不会走路的状态
4. Is this sentence correct? 累到不会走路
5. What's the difference between 穷到只能吃土的状态了 and 穷得只能吃土?

Comment: 2 了 is not part of the phrase. It ia attached to 穷到

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly right

“A 到 B 了” means "become so A that have got into the condition of B"

- A: adj, but used as a verb, which means "become A"
- B: a condition

"只能吃土" is a 状态 (condition) so it is the same as "只能吃土的状态"。

"到~" means "getting into" a 状态.

"了" means finished. There might be no "了", depending on the tense.

Correct example:

- 我很穷，（已经）**穷到只能吃土了**
- 我很穷，（已经）**穷到只能吃土的状态了**
- 赌博会让你 **穷到只能吃土**
- 赌博会让你 **穷到只能吃土的状态**

---

> Is it in fact a structure to create such sentences?

Yes

> 只能吃土的状态了 - I don't even know if I should treat it as a sentence or as a noun. So: what should come after 到?

As discussed above. 只能吃土的状态 is a 状态 which is a noun. 了 is following 到 indicating the tense.

> Is this sentence correct? 累到不会走路的状态

Correct, but not a complete sentence. Missing subject and tense indicator.

> Is this sentence correct? 累到不会走路

Correct. Same as above

> What's the difference between 穷到只能吃土的状态了 and 穷得只能吃土?

In 穷到只能吃土的状态, 穷 is an adj. but used as a verb, followed by the extent of this verb.
In 穷得只能吃土, 穷 is just an adj. followed by an adverb.

Both are correct and mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

this seems very analogous to the way we speak in English, i didnt even consider it anything special when I encountered it the first time;  到 means "to" and is being used in the exact same way we'd say "sad to the point of tears" or "happy to no end" in English.

So (some state) + 到 + (the extent/result of that state) reads exactly as it would in English. In your case it would be poor + to + (the extent of) only being able to eat dirt